# How do I upload a file to my sever and use it in my database

Tags: php, database, image

I designed a car selling website.

I have a form where certain information about cars is entered, it then is added to the database and displayed on my main form. How can I get the image to be sent to the server and then use a url as a source to the image.

Cheers.

Here is my code.

PHP:

```
<?php

try {
    # Connect to SQLite database
    $dbh = new PDO("sqlite:../Car_Sales_Network");

    $make = $_POST['Make'];
    $model = $_POST['Model'];
    $badge = $_POST['Badge'];
    $price = $_POST['Price'];
    $trans = $_POST['Transmission'];
    $ppl = $_POST['P_Plate_Legal'];

    print_r($_POST);

    $sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO Cars_On_Network
                         ("car_make","car_model","car_badge","price","trans","P_Plate_Legal")
                         VALUES
                         (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');

    $sth->execute(array($make, $model, $badge, $price, $trans, $ppl));

    header("Location: ../Carsales_Network.php");


}



catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>New Vehicle</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="New_Car_Form.css"/>
</head>

<body>
        <div id="main">
        <form action="Insert_Car.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Make:<br>
        <input type="text" name="Make">
        <br>
        Model:<br>
        <input type="text" name="Model">
        <br><br>
        Badge:<br>
        <input type="text" name="Badge">
        <br>
        Price:<br>
        <input type="text" name="Price">
        <br>


        Transmission: <br>
        <input type="radio" name="Transmission" value="Manual" checked>Manual
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="Transmission" value="Auto">Automatic
        <br><br>

        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_file.php" method="post">
        P Plate Legal: <br>
        <select name="P_Plate_Legal">
          <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
          <option value="No">No</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">

        </form>

        <br>
        <br>
        <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">



        <br>
        <a href="http://1673-itstudies/12-infotech/jsummers/Carsales_Network.php" class="myButton">Let's go back!</a>


        <br>







    </div>

</body>
</html>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I post the uploaded image to the database to be used, I have a folder on my database full of the cars photos.

Comment: i have created once its quite simple check code [here](https://github.com/swamimayank/drag-and-drop-file-uploader)

Comment: How are the photos named? You need to be able to generate the image filenames based on each car's database entry.

Comment: http://www.dropzonejs.com/ working for me, weird :/

Comment: Where about's do I add my information, I need it to upload to my server? Sorry but I'm really new to this. :)

Answer (score 0):

to upload files to server in php, use php fileupload function

```
move_uploaded_file ( string $filename , string $destination )
```

example:

```
<?php
  $uploads_dir = '/uploads';
  foreach ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
  if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"][$key];
    $name = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$key];
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
   }
  }
?>
```

for reference check [move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)